# SUDO permissions, file copy/chmod question?

Tags: linux, permissions, command-line-interface, files, copy

### So, I'm logged in as sudo, and seeing this... why?

---

```
$ cd /var/www/drupal-6.19/sites/default
$ ls
default.settings.php
$ sudo -v
[sudo] password for sudo_username:
$ cp default.settings.php settings.php
cp: cannot create regular file `settings.php': Permission denied
$ chmod 666 default.settings.php
chmod: changing permissions of `default.settings.php': Operation not permitted
```

---

**CONTEXT:** Drupal install that requires I copy a file (default.settings.php) and rename it as (settings.php) and then change the file permissions to (666).

Believe the question is clear, but if you have any questions, just ask! - Thanks!!

---

**UPDATE:** Wow, thanks for all the quick replies, they're all correct. Selected the answer based on response time as a result. Again, thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not sudoing, you're just extending your sudo password timeout for 5 minutes. Precede the last two commands with "sudo" and it should work. If not, check the files/directories aren't immutable (lsattr file) and check getenforce.

Comment: **@James Lawrie:** Thanks, your answer is correct, and you beat everyone else by 1-min... So, I'm selecting you as **the answer** and gave you a +1 up vote too - again, thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

Try...

```
sudo su
```

To change to root then run the commands. I'm not sure what distro you're using but -v won't change you to root I don't think.

http://www.sudo.ws/sudo/sudo.man.html

Alternatively you can run the commands with sudo before them....

```
sudo cp default.settings.php settings.php
sudo chmod 666 settings.php
```

Comment: **@chunkyb2002:** Thanks, your answer is correct, but 1-min behind James Lawrie, and I need to select an answer; so I'm awarding the answer based on time. Gave you a +1 up vote though - again, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

How are you logged in as `sudo`? Is this your username ? Seriously:

```
sudo cp default.settings.php settings.php


sudo chmod 666 default.settings.php
```

or use:

```
sudo -i
```

Comment: **@Casual_Coder:** Thanks, your answer is correct, but 1-min behind James Lawrie, and I need to select an answer; so I'm awarding the answer based on time. Gave you a +1 up vote though - again, thanks!!